# Map VPN clients to AD site

Tags: active-directory

I want to be able to map my VPN clients to a domain controller. For these clients, I am seeing the Netlogon eventid 5807 (client machines who IP addresses dont map to any existing sites in the enterprise).

These machine connect via a sonciwall VPN. The VPN at the main site configures the dhcp for the clients on the vpn client side. Subnets for these locations are not yet defined in AD.

I want to be able to specify which domain controller these computers log on to. I have several domain controllers in the network and some are in different locations.

I attempted to set this up in Active Directory Sites and Services, but I couldnt get it figured out. I am not sure what needs to be created first, I cannot create a site without a site link and I cannot create a site link without a site. Since there is no DC on the VPN client side, I am not sure how to do this or even if I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little tricky for a couple of reasons. First, let me outline how you make the sites, then I'll explain why it's tricky.

To make the site:

- Create a site object for each physical site that you have that has a DC in it.
- Create subnet objects for all of them based on their IP space (if your sites share a subnet, you don't do this and you won't benefit from using sites). You can assign multiple subnets to a single site.
- Add the subnet that VPN users get assigned to the corresponding site that has the DCs that you want them to use.
- Create site links between the sites so that you can set a replication interval and all that other fun stuff.
- Move Domain Controller objects into the appropriate sites.

This is a [well documented thing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730868.aspx) and you should really read through the documentation to get a feel for it. Sites have a big impact on things like replication, DFS referrals, Exchange/Outlook, and plenty of other things.

---

Why is it tricky? Well, when a client *first* logs on to a domain, it uses a random domain controller. Then, it becomes "site aware" and knows that it belongs in a specific site. It caches this information and continues to use it. If that machine moves to a different site, it will first try to authenticate to the old one and one it does, it will realize that it's in a new site and update its cache for future logins. If these are laptops that rapidly change which location they're in, you might not see a lot of benefit - you should still set up sites though, it's best practice.

Comment: The OP shouldn't have to manually create site links. The KCC  should generate the intrasite replication topology automatically. The KCC running on the ISTG in each site should generate the intersite topology automatically. All the OP should have to do is to create the sites and subnets and move the DC's to the appropriate site container.

Comment: Do you have any documentation that recommends not configuring site links? I've always been under the impression that creating them and assigning sites to them is best practice (and MS AD certification exams test this way). Are you sure you're not talking about assigning bridgehead servers (which the KCC/ITSG will do automatically and is usually just fine to leave on autopilot)?

Comment: No I don't. When creating a new site you have to select a site link object for the site. There's only one by default (DEFAULTIPSITELINK). It's not possible to create a new site without selecting a site link and the only choice (if no other site links have been created) is the default DEFAULTIPSITELINK, so no manual site link creation is required unless you plan to create site links based on your WAN topology. Do I have this wrong or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I've only ever created site links based on the WAN topology, so that I could have granular control over replication intervals and site link cost for replication to the DR site as well (think hub-spoke with two hubs). Honestly, I didn't even realize that a default site link was created. Seems like either way would work if the OP doesn't need granularity in the link settings.

Comment: You're making a simple thing too complicated if you have to think about KCCs and ISTGs here. When a computer logs on to a domain, the NetLogon service uses DNS to locate a domain controller. Site-specific DNS records are registered by the DCs based on which sites you assigned them to. As MDMarra said, a client figures out which site he belongs to after his first authentication if his IP address is represented in a subnet object. Voila. You've defined what DC a client will prefer to log on to.

Comment: @RyanRies I think we've made the common sysadmin error of having two differing ways of looking at the same thing (which is only a minor piece of the actual question) and being completely sidetracked by it. heh

Comment: @RyanRies - You're right. MD and I got off onto a slight side-track about replication topology and site links (my fault).

Comment: Great conversation! Maybe I didn't make clear OR I am not getting it: These sites don't have DC's in them. When I create their subnetwhat site am I giving it? I don't have a site configured because as I understand it a site has to have a DC? EDIT: Ahh the subnet site is the DC at the main site it authenticates too!

Comment: What would the site link be between the remote site and the main site? I still feel like I need something on the remote site to designate it as a 'site'.

Comment: You don't need to create a new site for your VPN clients. Just add their IP subnets to the already existing site that hosts the DCs that you want the VPN clients to authenticate to. You don't even have to think about site links at all. Site links are for inter-site replication among DCs, which is not what you're concerned with right now.